# Mixing 2 columns in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, combine, column

Good Morning

I'm trying to "combine" two columns in Excel. Not concatenating them, but "mixing" the result

For example, I have these 2 columns:

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |

And I want two new columns, looking like this, where every register of column 1 is matched with every register of column 2

| Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| a | 3 |
| b | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 1 |
| c | 2 |
| c | 3 |

Thank you!
Regards

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please have a read of https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask, then come back and update your question.

Comment: Hi, first I tried the old copy-paste, but with big columns is unmanageable doing it row by row. I have tried reading about Combinatorics, but none of the statisticals functions seem appropiate.

Comment: @MarcosC Welcome! Does your version of Excel have a [**TEXTJOIN() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)?

Comment: Hi John, thank you. Yes, it is included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Sorry, unfortunately, I will not be able to illustrate the sequence of actions with screenshots.*

Convert your source table to Table **Ctrl+T**

Set name of table as `SourceTable`

Go to tab **Data** and choose **From table**

Open Editor and replace code of M-script with

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SourceTable"]}[Content],
    NameOfSecondColumn = Table.ColumnNames(Source){1},
    AddSecondColumn = Table.AddColumn(Source, "SetOfValues", each Table.Column(Source, NameOfSecondColumn)),
    DeleteSecondColumn = Table.RemoveColumns(AddSecondColumn,{NameOfSecondColumn}),
    RenameColumn = Table.RenameColumns(DeleteSecondColumn,{{"SetOfValues", NameOfSecondColumn}}),
    ExpandResult = Table.ExpandListColumn(RenameColumn, NameOfSecondColumn)
in
    ExpandResult
```

Close and save.

Comment: Works as a charm, you have opened a new door. Thank you!